# php Tesseract Error! The command "tesseract" was not found

Tags: php, tesseract

I'm trying and failing to use tesseract php. I get this error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractNotFoundException: Error! The command "tesseract" was not found. Make sure you have Tesseract OCR installed on your system: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract 
The current $PATH is C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Peppe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Peppe\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin in C:\Users\Peppe\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\FriendlyErrors.php:48 Stack trace: #0 
C:\Users\Peppe\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\TesseractOCR.php(26): thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\FriendlyErrors::checkTesseractPresence('tesseract') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(7): thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR->run() #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Peppe\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\FriendlyErrors.php on line 48
```

I'm using windows 10 with xampp installed in C:\xampp. php version 7.4
I installed tesseract.exe from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki both x32 and x64
I used composer to install the https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php and it gave no error.

```
<?php
require_once 'C:\Users\Peppe\vendor\autoload.php';  

use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
$ocr = new TesseractOCR("caption.jpg");
$content = $ocr->run();
echo $content;

?>
```

finally, the caption.jpg is in the htdocs folder, the main folder and same folder as index.php where the aforementioned code appears.

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
the $PATH variable is taken from Windows. To set it right search for "system environment variables", click "environment variables", edit PATH and add the tesseract software folder, for example C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to add new variable `tesseract` with full path `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe` as showing in below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To install TESSERACT OCR and use it in PHP

You must perform the following steps:
(in my explanation, I assume you are on windows)
url src = https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html

1- Download the TESSERACT software from URL:
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

2- From your composer, you must install:
url: https://packagist.org/packages/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr
composer require thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr

3- Then, it is important to do things in the following order:
Your TESSERACT software (step 1) is installed in a directory
which will certainly be (it's up to you to check in your system)
folder = C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR

**It is absolutely necessary to add this folder in the windows environment variables at the PATH level (user and system)**

4- Then you restart your web environment (WAMP, LARAGON ...)

5- Verification that TESSERACT is operational.
Go to your CMD and write:
tesseract --version

```
Reply somethink like that :
tesseract v5.3.0.20221222
leptonica-1.78.0
libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
Found AVX2
Found AVX
Found FMA
Found SSE4.1
Found libarchive 3.5.0 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5 libzstd/1.4.5
Found libcurl/7.77.0-DEV Schannel zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.4.5 libidn2/2.0.4 nghttp2/1.31.0
```

6- Operation test from a PHP script
uses an image on a white background with text

```
<?php

    $app_class = 'thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR';
    $file = 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/im2.jpg';
    
    $class = new ReflectionClass($app_class);
    $infoImg = $class->newInstanceArgs();
    $infoImg->lang('eng','jpn','spa','fr');
    $infoImg->image($file);
    $infoImg->withoutTempFiles();
    $resultat = $infoImg->run();
    var_dump($resultat);
?>
```